# joint distribution of random variables

Tags: joint-distribution

Let   ,   and    be discrete random variables with  ,   and    possible outcomes respectively. so the number of parameters that define the joint distribution is `n*m*k-1`
And When they are independent number of parameters is `(n+m+k)-3`

can you please explain why this is the number of parameters in each case?

Comment: Your question doesn't give enough context to give a proper answer. It looks like you're perhaps talking about a joint (multivariate) multinomial distribution under the general case and under independence but then the term "discrete" seems odd, it's a categorical random element rather than a discrete random variable but we shouldn't be guessing at the situation . You need to explain more clearly what this is about. You seem to be quoting text from something. What is it from?

Comment: @Glen This looks clear enough to me.  It all comes down to parameterizing the most general distribution supported on at most $n$ points, applied successively to the cases of $nmk,$ $n,$ $m,$ and $k$ points along with a definition of independence.

Comment: Yes, indeed that could be the case - that would fit the 'discrete' part - but then I'd prefer that something equivalent to 'the most general distribution supported on n points' was actually stated in the question.

Comment: @Glen Fair enough.  Because the question asks why $nmk-1$ and $n+m+k-3$ are the answers, that supplies enough information to deduce the intended meaning.

Comment: this is all the data I have in the question but we got additional clarification:
*Parameters can be any values used to define a distribution. In the HW question, we mean in the most general case (in particular, no distribution type is assumed). For example, to define the distribution of a single (not necessarily fair) die, you would need 5 values (parameters).
*X can get n possible values, Y can get m possible values, and Z can get k possible values.

Comment: Please add extra information as an edit, not only in comments!